# Creating Custom UI for Change Password Screen

Tags: windows, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

I want to customize the change password screen by adding some new password requirements as a simple text or label. I am working on a VM that has an AD server with a list of users to whom I can connect through an RDP connection. Due to the lack of experience and knowledge, as a starting point, I am using the sample provided by Microsoft (https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/CredentialProvider). Even though my final goal is to actually apply new password requirements, for now, I just want to know how I can customize the change password screen.

I couldn't find useful articles or documentation that would clearly define the steps or explain the procedure, therefore I am asking whether someone could give me some piece of advice or attach links to useful posts and articles.

Comment: Were sorry, but questions that are just requests for offsite resources are not allowed here.